# How does in_array check if an object is in an array of objects?

Tags: php, object-comparison

Does `in_array()` do object comparison where it checks that all attributes are the same?
What if `$obj1 === $obj2`, will it just do pointer comparison instead?

I'm using an ORM, so I'd rather loop over the objects testing if `$obj1->getId()` is already in the array if it does object comparison. If not, `in_array` is much more concise.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) does *loose* comparisons (`$a == $b`) unless you pass `TRUE` to the third argument, in which case it does *strict* comparisons (`$a === $b`).

Semantically, `in_array($obj, $arr)` is identical to this:

```
foreach ($arr as &$member) {
  if ($member == $obj) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
return FALSE;
```

...and `in_array($obj, $arr, TRUE)` is identical to this:

```
foreach ($arr as &$member) {
  if ($member === $obj) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
return FALSE;
```

...and to quote the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) on what this actually checks:

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.
>
> On the other hand, when using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. There's a stupid timer, so I can't accept for another 5 mintues.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always references in PHP 5+ and can only be copied (thus creating a new object) by using `clone`.

That means you should be able to use `in_array()`.