# PHP in_array object comparing?

Tags: php

Can the `in_array` function compare objects?

For example, I have an array of objects and I want to add them distinctly to another array. Is it possible to check if an object has already been added like so:

```
in_array($distinct, $object);
```

or is there any other way?

Comment: What's your definition of "distinct"? If "distinct" is the opposite of reference equality then simply passing in `true` as the third parameter will do it.

Comment: So this will work with objects in array?

Comment: For some definition of "work". You need to give more details, mind reading is hard.

Comment: Does [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743592/170403) for similar question helps you?

Comment: what means distinct, its unclear what you want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** function cannot compare objects.

You should create unique key-value pairs from your objects and only need to compare those keys when inserting a new object into your final array.

Assuming that each object has an unique `id` property, a possible solution would be:

```
$unique_objects = array();

// $data represents your object collection
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!array_key_exists($item->id, $unique_objects)) {
        $unique_objects[$item->id] = $obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, what? $idem isn't a variable anywhere, and neither is $obj? How was this up voted 13 times?

Comment: Good point. I've updated the response to fix the `$idem` typo.

The assumption with this sample code is that `$obj` simply represents an existing variable that needs to be uniquely added to the `$unique_objects` array.

Comment: Of course `in_array` can compare objects, strictly speaking. This answer should be unaccepted and deleted as it states false infos.

Answer (score 38):

You can use strict comparison:

```
in_array($object, $array, TRUE);
```

Usage example:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->x = 42;

$b = new stdClass();
$b->y = 42;

$c = new stdClass();
$c->x = 42;

$array = array($a,$b);

echo in_array($a, $array, true); // 1
echo in_array($b, $array, true); // 1
echo in_array($c, $array, true); //
```

Comment: Due to the broad title of the question, I like to add that when you want to find any object from a different class, this won't work. Only finding exactly the same instance of an object works with strict comparison.

Answer (score 7):

I did some tests comparing objects with the `in_array` function. This is my conclusion:

When you try to find the **same instance of an object** in an array (like OP), then `in_array` could work with the strict comparison boolean set.

When you try to find **any object of the same class but with a different instance**, `in_array` shows counter-intuitive behavior.

There is a [great user comment on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#106319) about the counter-intuitive edge cases.

> ```
> // Example array
>
> $array = array(
>     'egg' => true,
>     'cheese' => false,
>     'hair' => 765,
>     'goblins' => null,
>     'ogres' => 'no ogres allowed in this array'
> );
>
> // Loose checking -- return values are in comments
>
> // First three make sense, last four do not
>
> in_array(null, $array); // true
> in_array(false, $array); // true
> in_array(765, $array); // true
> in_array(763, $array); // true
> in_array('egg', $array); // true
> in_array('hhh', $array); // true
> in_array(array(), $array); // true
>
> // Strict checking
>
> in_array(null, $array, true); // true
> in_array(false, $array, true); // true
> in_array(765, $array, true); // true
> in_array(763, $array, true); // false
> in_array('egg', $array, true); // false
> in_array('hhh', $array, true); // false
> in_array(array(), $array, true); // false
> ```

As you can see that without strict checking the `in_array` tests 4 - 7 don't make sense.

We [know from PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) that two objects are *only* the same in strict comparison (`===`) when they are from the same class + instance. Two objects are *already* the same in loose comparison (`==`) when they are from the same class.

I wrote some tests with objects to see what happens.

```
$a = new stdClass();                              
$a->egg = true;                                   

$b = new stdClass();                              
$b->cheese = false;                               

$c = new stdClass();                              
$c->hair = 765;                                   

$d = new stdClass();                              
$d->goblins = null;                               

$e = new stdClass();                              
$e->ogres = 'no ogres allowed in this array';     

$array2 = array($a, $b, $c,  $d, $e);         

$e = new stdClass();                                            
$e->egg = null;                                                 

$f = new stdClass();                                            
$f->egg = false;                                                

$g = new stdClass();                                            
$g->egg = 765;                                                  

$h = new stdClass();                                            
$h->egg = 763;                                                  

$i = new stdClass();                                            
$i->egg = 'egg';                                                

$j = new stdClass();                                            
$j->egg = 'hhh';                                                

$k = new stdClass();                                            
$k->egg = array();                                              

in_array($e, $array2, false); // false                
in_array($f, $array2, false); // false                
in_array($g, $array2, false); // true                 
in_array($h, $array2, false); // true                 
in_array($i, $array2, false); // true                 
in_array($j, $array2, false); // true                 
in_array($k, $array2, false); // false                

in_array($e, $array2, true); // false                 
in_array($f, $array2, true); // false                 
in_array($g, $array2, true); // false                 
in_array($h, $array2, true); // false                 
in_array($i, $array2, true); // false                 
in_array($j, $array2, true); // false                 
in_array($k, $array2, true); // false
```

In the last checks `in_array` checks 3 - 6 give counter-intuitive results.

The reason is as follow. If you try to find any object with a certain value, you are forced to use loose comparison (because when the class is not the same, strict comparison always fails). But due to [PHP's variable types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), in the last tests these checks are considered true, because the value is considered truthy. Also note that the key on the object is ignored in loose comparison.

Answer (score 3):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php

```
if ( ! array_key_exists( spl_object_hash( $obj ), $objects ) ) {
    $objects[ spl_object_hash( $obj ) ] = $obj;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

There's numerous ways you can do this as you can see. I just thought I would add another one. I don't know why, but when working with object arrays I like to use the array functions which use callbacks.

If your objects have any sort of identifier, which they should if you want to test them for duplication, the following will work:

```
$found = array_filter($uniqueObjects, function($uniqueObject) use ($object) {
    return $uniqueObject->id == $object->id
});

if (!$found) {
    $uniqueObjects[] = $object;
}
```

`$object` is the object you're looking for, and `$uniqueObjects` is the array of objects you're searching to see if it exists. Just match uniqueObject and object on an identifying property, such as an `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is because of a newer PHP version, but in my project, using PHP 5.3.16 on Ubuntu 12.04, it worked. It found the needle object in my array of objects. I have also double-checked by loading a different object of the same class, and testing it against the array contents which did not contain that object, and it returned false indeed.

So yes, `in_array` can compare objects.

Answer (score 0):

If "STRICT" is "FALSE", the comparison is made by converting in a string the elements. So if you override the __toString magic function, you should be available to compare the objects elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a somewhat different, I think more robust, option.

```
function array_add_unique(&$array, $new, $test, $cb) {
  if(is_array($array) && count($array)>0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
      if( $array[$i][$test] == $new[$test] ) {
        $do = $cb($array[$i], $new);
        if(is_bool($do) && $do) { $array[$i] = $new; }
        else if(!is_bool($do)) { $array[$i] = $do; }
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  array_push($array, $new);
}
```

The benefit to this solution, is it includes a user definable callback to handle collisions.  When your adding unique objects, you may want to preserve properties from both the old and the new object.

The callback, which can be an anonymous function, receives both the new object and the existing object so the user can have a custom calculation.  Return *true* to simply replace the existing object, or return a new object (non-bool) to replace it.

I do not know the performance of this on large datasets though.