# Php check if object with property exists in array

Tags: php

Let's assume I have the following PHP code:

```
$a = new a();
$a->id = 1;
```

I then have an array `$m` of objects of type type a (but they really could be of any type). I want to check if any object in m has property id equal to 1. In Java, I'd do something like:

```
myList
.stream()
.filter(x <- x.id == a.id)
.count();
```

In PHP I tried

```
in_array($a, $m)
```

but that didn't seem to do work, because obviously even if another object had the same ID it would still be a different object.

I could obviously use a loop, but as really I'd want to check if any object in an array `n` had a corresponding object with the same ID in `m` I'd rather avoid a nested loop.

Comment: Looking for in_array($a->id, $m)????

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231925/php-in-array-object-comparing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP also has an array filtering functioning, which (for obvious reasons) is called [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and does what you want, with anonymous functions.

```
function findAllWithId($objects, $id) {
    return array_filter($objects, function($toCheck) use ($id) { 
        return $toCheck->id == $id; 
    });
}
```

Comment: Should you add `$objects` as a function's parameter?

Comment: @A.L Yep, It should be.

Comment: there are two syntax errors, missing object in arg and use( $id )

Comment: This is what I get for coding after midnight :+ Fixed.

Comment: I think it would be a lot clearer whether `$toCheck` was renamed to `$object` instead. Also, It seems function is not need here. Anyway, nice answer.