# Comparing PHP Object Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to iterate over two sets of arrays and if they match or do not match then they need to be styled different.

A quick working example is:

```
$animal1 = array('elephant', 'giraffe', 'lion');
$animal2 = array('elephant', 'giraffe', 'cow');
$animal3 = array('elephant', 'lion', 'giraffe');

foreach($animal1 as $animal) {
    echo $animal . " ";
    if(in_array($animal, $animal2, true)) {
        echo "yay<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "no<br />";
    }
}
```

The problem is my that my arrays actually contain objects instead of just data. When I var_dump($example) I'll get something like the following:

```
array (size=1)
    0 => 
        object(stdClass)[200]
            public 'id' => int 3
            public 'c_name' => string 'AFAM-202-001-2015Spring' (length=23)
            public 'c_avail' => string 'Y' (length=1)
   1 => 
        object(stdClass)[201]
            public 'id' => int 4
            public 'c_name' => string 'IDES-203-001-2015Spring' (length=23)
            public 'c_avail' => string 'Y' (length=1)
```

So working my $example array into the first example doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas how I can do this? Apparently in_object doesn't exist in PHP ...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert objects to arrays with `(array)` type cast.
Say, you have an object `$obj`.
Do `$arr = (array)$obj;`
That's it, you have an array with exactly same keys as the property names were.
Everything else's the same!

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for a string to a value within an object found in an array, you could write your own `in_array` function:

```
function in_array_of_objects($needle, $haystack, $objValue) {
    foreach ($haystack as $obj) {
        if ($needle === $obj->$objValue) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then:

```
if (in_array_of_objects($animal, $example, 'c_name')) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to preserve strict functionality:

```
function in_array_of_objects($needle, $haystack, $objValue, $strict = false) {
    if ($strict) {
        foreach ($haystack as $obj) {
            if ($needle === $obj->$objValue) return true;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $obj) {
            if ($needle == $obj->$objValue) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note I prevented adding the `$strict` check to the if-statement inside of the `foreach` loop to cut down on processing time, however marginal it may be.

However, assuming all of the arrays actually contain objects and you're comparing objects with objects, [`in_array` should work if you turn the `$strict` parameter off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743592/1188035)...

```
$test = new stdClass();
$test->one = 'one';
$test->two = 'two';
$test->three = 'three';

$array = array($test, $test, $test, $test); // Same object instance

var_dump(in_array($test, $array, true)); // bool(true)

var_dump(in_array($test, $array)); // bool(true)

$newTest = clone $test; // New object instance, will fail strict checks

var_dump(in_array($newTest, $array, true)); // bool(false)

var_dump(in_array($newTest, $array)); // bool(true)

$newTest = new stdClass();
$newTest->one = 'two';
$newTest->two = 'two';
$newTest->three = 'three';

// To ensure that classes with varying values do not satisfy in_array
var_dump(in_array($newTest, $array)); // bool(false)
```

However they must still be instances of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function Checks if **a value** exists in an array, not objects.

Comparing objects is not the same way to compare values. Look at this [Comparing Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)
Said that you should change your code

Try this:

```
foreach ($arr as &$member) {
  if ($member == $obj) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
return FALSE;
```

or this:

```
foreach ($arr as &$member) {
  if ($member === $obj) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
return FALSE;
```

Note: you can see how to create a function to compare objects in precedent link Comparing Objects

Comment: A "value" can be an object. The docs for `in_array` accept a `mixed` value for the `$needle`. And your examples are exactly what `in_array` does, where example #1 is `$strict = false` and example #2 is `$strict = true`.